# angular 1.5 component call back function parameter passing

Tags: angularjs, components

How to pass row object to the callback function component.

commonGridComponent:

```
.component('commonGridComponent', {
  templateUrl: 'public/templates/commonGridComponent.tpl.html',
 bindings: {
options: '=', 
headersList: '<', 
gridData: '=',
gridCallBack: '&'
},
 controller: 'commonGridController',
controllerAs:'vm'
   });
```

commonGridController:

```
.controller('commonGridController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
     var vm = this; // jshint ignore:line
     }]);
```

commonGridComponent.tpl.html:

```
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="rowData in vm.gridData">
<td  ng-repeat="(key, value) in rowData" ng-click="vm.gridCallBack(rowData)">{{value}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

parent html:

```
 <common-grid-component options="xx" headers-list="xx", grid-data="vm.data" grid-call-back="vm.onSelectRow()"></common-grid-component>
```

parent controller:

```
vm.onSelectRow= function (rowData){
console.log("onSelectRowonSelectRowonSelectRow", rowData);
};
```

row data I am getting here is undefined. Please suggest me

Comment: But you are not passing the rowData back to the function so it will always be undefined. Try changing grid-call-back="vm.onSelectRow()" to grid-call-back="vm.onSelectRow(vm.data)" or similar and see if that works

Comment: Yes, I am passing it now and I got the results.. Thanks for the support